# Discontinuity of $\log x$ at $x=0$

Tags: calculus

So $\frac{1}{\log|x|}$ is discontinuous for $x \in \{1,-1,0\}$ however $\log(\frac{1+x}{1-x})$ is continuous everywhere . I know $0$ is a cluster point for $\log x$ then why is zero not a point of discontinuity for $\log x$

Comment: Do you mean $\log\frac{1+x}{1-x}$?

Comment: $\ln(x)$ is neither continuous nor discontinuous at $x=0$ because $\lim_{x \to 0^-}\ln(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: Why is ln|x| discontinuous at 0 then? 0 is a cluster point for both lnx as well as ln|x|

Comment: As you suggested about the left hand limit being non existent is that not the definition of a cluster point? Because we only check continuity at cluster points and if the curve of a function exist within a small neighborhood of the given point "a" then it is a cluster point( even if the curve exist only on one side of the point) that concludes that 0 indeed is a cluster point for logx that means we'll check continuity there